# Googlemaps API: problems getting my key

Tags: android, api, google-maps

i am doing a debug key and i can't. Im stuck here:

"Once you have located the keystore, use this Keytool command to get the MD5 fingerprint of the debug certificate:

$ keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey \
-keystore .keystore \
-storepass android -keypass android"

i located my keystore, but i dont know how to put that order.... i think that order is for linux, and i am using windows XP Professional

can someone help me plz?

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the backslashes. Those, in Linux and OS X, denote line continuations.

So, in Windows, if you are in the directory containing your debug keystore, you should be able to run:

```
keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```